# Conflicting Mongoid versions with Heroku/MongoHQ

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have a Rails 3.2 app I'm trying to get going on Heroku using Mongoid and MongoHQ and I've found that I have to use a different version of the Mongoid gem for local development vs Heroku.
Here is what I have found;

To get the app working on Heroku and MongoHQ I have to use Mongoid 2.4.11
To get the app working locally I have to use Mongoid 3.0.0.rc

Here are the errors I am getting;

Mongoid 2.4.10 locally,

```
undefined class/module Moped::
```

Mongoid 3.0.0.rc on Heroku/MongoHQ

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
```

Why the incompatibility?

Comment: v2.4.10 should use 10gen driver, not moped.

Comment: I think thats the problem, it's looking for Moped, but it's not there.  I'm not sure why. I started with the sample app at railsapps.github.com/ which was using 3.0.0.rc.